# How to build a carrier-neutral data center?

Tags: ipv4, datacenter, isp

We need to set up a very small datacenter. This needs to be carrier-neutral. What are the things we need to do to make it a carrier-neutral datacenter?

I assume that we need internet connections from multiple internet service providers (ISPs). If one network is down then we can switch to another one. But, how can we keep the IPs of the servers the same, even after switching the ISP? Normally, changing the ISP changes the server computer's IPs.

Comment: Carrier neutral datacenters suggest to me a datacenter  that won't be operated exclusively by and for one customer, but that a (co-location) datacenter operator rents out rack space, rows of racks and cages/suites to third parties. Those customers are not required to use IP-space that belongs to the datacenter operator, they can connect to the ISP's of their choice. Typically several ISP's/transit providers etc. will  already present and/or will be allowed access to a [meet-me-room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-me_room) and patches can be made from there to their racks/cages/suites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is [Autonomous system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)). This will help you route the same IPs independently of the provider. Here is the first paragraph from the link:

> An autonomous system (AS) is a collection of connected Internet
> Protocol (IP) routing prefixes under the control of one or more
> network operators on behalf of a single administrative entity or
> domain, that presents a common and clearly defined routing policy to
> the Internet.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autonomous_system_(Internet)) Each AS is assigned an autonomous system number
> (ASN), for use in Border Gateway Protocol (BGP) routing. Autonomous
> System Numbers are assigned to Local Internet Registries (LIRs) and
> end user organizations by their respective Regional Internet
> Registries (RIRs), which in turn receive blocks of ASNs for
> reassignment from the Internet Assigned Numbers Authority (IANA). The
> IANA also maintains a registry of ASNs which are reserved for private
> use (and should therefore not be announced to the global Internet).

As it is explained in comment:

> In other words: unlike the typical "consumer and small business"
> internet connectivity that comes with only the public IP-addresses
> owned by the ISP, you will be using your own / provider independent
> public IP-address range(s). That allows traffic to and from your
> IP-range(s) to be routed via different ISP's , different carriers.

Comment: erm, not quite. Something expensive, difficult to test and maintain is not a requirement. Just use SNAT/proxying at the edge instead of DNAT.

Answer (score 0):

To repeat and expand on my initial comment:

Carrier neutral datacenters suggest to me a datacenter that won't be operated exclusively by and for one customer, or by an ISP, but a datacenter where a (co-location) datacenter operator rents out rack space, rows of racks and cages/suites to third parties.

Those third-parties, those customers are ***not required to use IP-space that belongs to the datacenter operator***, (optionally) their rack space comes with neither internet connectivity/bandwidth nor IP-addresses,  but rather ***they can connect to the ISP('s) of their choice***.

Typically that is facilitated by having several ISP's/transit providers etc. already present and/or allowing them access to what's commonly called a centralized [meet-me-room](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-me_room) and patches can be made from there to the racks/cages/suites of the customers that want to subscribe to a particular ISP. That significantly reduces the amount of cabling required and often reduces or even eliminates the lead time whenever a (new) datacenter customer wants to subscribe to a new/different/additional ISP/transit provider.

**Note** that doesn't require that the customers of the carrier neutral datacenter all need to have their own provider independent IP-address ranges and/or ASN's. (They can still choose to use public IP-addresses from ISP of their choice.)  Nor does it require that they subscribe to two or more different ISP's.  A single ISP can (and often will) provide two independent lines (to that meet-me-room) providing full redundancy there and their customers  can connect with two patches from the meet-me-room to their own equipment.

Some carrier neutral datacenters will allow also interconnects to be made  between their customers directly and not only to/from ISP's and/or offer facilities for public/private [peering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peering).

Comment: Thanks @HBruijn. Our requirement is not to use a colocation service from another data center provider. We intend to build a small data center for our customers. We already have a 'cloud management software' and we provide Virtual Machine instances to our customers.  Right now, we are depending on a data center from a third party.